# How can I access DynamoDB table from AccountA with using AccountB's User CLI credentials?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

I have created one table in Dynamodb and setup role in IAM with following policy attached:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "dynamodb:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:ap-south-1:**AccountAID**:table/employee"
  }]
}
```

I have added trusted entity AccountB ID in the role. Then I have also created policy in AccountB for the access of dynamodb table created in AccountA with following policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::**AccountAID**:role/DynamodbCrossAccountAccessRole"
    }]
}
```

I have configured profiles of AccountA user and AccountB user and with the credentials of AccountA's profile user, I can list tables of dynamodb but while trying to get with AccountB's profile user I always returns with empty-table list.

> `Krunal-MacBook-Air:.aws krunal$ aws dynamodb list-tables --profile Krunal
>   {
>       "TableNames": [
>           "employee"
>       ]
>   }
>   Krunal-MacBook-Air:.aws krunal$ aws dynamodb list-tables --profile Krunal2
>   {
>       "TableNames": []
>   }`

Can anyone help me out of this why am I not able to access dynamodb with AccountB's profile?
Policies are attached to the account users respectively.

Comment: In Account A you need to have `assumable` role which can be assumed by an entity (user or role) in Account B. The assumable role allows access to the table in Account A. Form you description it does not seem you have assumable role in Account A, and that you actually assume the role in Account B.

Comment: thanks @Marcin I can see that the trust relationship policy is something like this in my AccountA
`
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::AccountBID:root"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {}
    }
  ]
}
`

Comment: Yes, So trust policy seems OK. Now in AccountB you have to use STS `AssumeRole`to actually assume the role from AccountA to be able to use DdB.

Comment: Thank you @Marcin I had followed the same thing and created policy with service STS and added ARN into resource with AccountA's role ARN and created policy like this:

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::AccountAID:role/DynamodbCrossAccountAccessRole"
    }
}

Comment: [AssumeRole](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html) is an STS API call. You call it to assume role in AccountA. The call will give you temporary credentials which will allow you to use DynamoDb in AccountA.

Comment: I have attached this policy to the AccountB's user and tried with AccountB's credentials profile and it returns the same:

Krunal-MacBook-Air:.aws krunal$ aws dynamodb list-tables --profile Krunal2
  {
      "TableNames": []
  }

Comment: @Marcin but that credentials will allow me to access DynamoDB from AccountA's user only right? but I am looking for the AccountB's user also.

Comment: Please have a look [here](https://stelligent.com/2016/07/12/cross-account-access-control-with-amazon-sts-for-dynamodb/) or [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html#tutorial_cross-account-with-roles-3). These examples should enable you to use `STS` in AccountB to assume role from AccountA. Once you assume the role, you should be able to access dynamodb in AccountA.

Comment: thank you @Marcin I went through this and did this thank you so much

Comment: So I guess its working and I can make an answer for future reference?

Comment: @Marcin yes its working as expected and this helped me a lot to configure AssumeRole credentials to access AccountA's resources and again thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was solved by assuming the role in AccountB. The useful links showing how to do this are:

- [Cross-Account Access Control with Amazon STS for DynamoDB](https://stelligent.com/2016/07/12/cross-account-access-control-with-amazon-sts-for-dynamodb/)
- [Delegate Access Across AWS Accounts Using IAM Roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html#tutorial_cross-account-with-roles-3)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments and with the help of provided documents, I can access to my AccountB's resources. I have configured generated API Key, Secret Key and Tokens in credentials file of my profile and it's working as expected.